# Google Translate vs. Google Cloud Translate

Tags: google-translate, google-cloud-translate

Google Cloud Translation offers Neural Machine Translation (NMT) and Phrase-Based Machine Translation (PBMT). It is stated that "nmt model is used if the language pair is supported, otherwise the PBMT model is used."(https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/advanced/translating-text-v3).

Does Google Translate web (https://translate.google.com) work in the same way? Does it use exactly the same NMT model as cloud translate API?